# Can't input chinese in Pinyin after upgrade to ubuntu 14.04 from 12.04

Tags: ubuntu, input

I recently upgraded Ubuntu 12.04 to the newly released 14.04. However, the Pinyin input stopped working. The display bar is listing all the possible Chinese Characters, but after selecting, the text editor only shows Invalid UTF-8.

I tried to reinstall ibus-pinyin. However, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 6):

OK, it turns out that ibus-pinyin is broken after upgrade. 
There are two ways to fix the problem.

**First approach** ( credited to Xiang Xiao @ http://oct.im/upgrade-1204lts-to-1404-lts-problems-and-fixes.html)

1. open a terminal
2. sudo apt-get install language-selector-gnome (skip this step if language support is installed)
3. ibus-daemon -drx

**Second Approach** ( credited to Aaron Lu @ https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1002417)

1. delete Chinese input text entry setting
2. sudo apt-get remove ibus-pinyin
3. sudo apt-get install ibus-libpinyin
4. select intelligent pinyin from text entry setting

Comment: Second approach worked best for me but needs a reboot after 3rd step. Also the input method suits me and my wife (chinese) better. I also changed to that method on my laptop where the pinyin was kind of working but not really since my wife couldn't find some characters.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the 1st approach posted by user3092403 but it doesn't work for me, until I did the following:

1. open a terminal
2. im-config
3. click "Yes" when being asked "Do you explicitly select the user configuration?"
4. select ibus from the list and click "OK"
5. restart X (or reboot)

Comment: I think he's trying to share a solution that worked for him

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try [ibus-sunpinyin](http://www.pinyinjoe.com/faq/ubuntu-1404-chinese-ime-problems-faq.htm).

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get purge ibus-pinyin
sudo apt-get install ibus-sunpinyin
killall ibus-daemon
ibus-daemon -d
# add intelligent pinyin in chinese language,
sudo reboot
```

Then is should be ok, by the way ibus-sunpinyin seems a new version of ibus-pinyin.